# Laravel client-secret API security (laravel-passport)

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth-2.0

Making an Laravel 5.5 API app (will be using with Vue.js app on remote server and iOS/android apps). My question is about secure my client-secret token. As I know, after `passport:install` I can use my tokens for retrieving data like this:

```
let data = {
   grant_type: 'password',
   client_id: 2,
   client_secret: 'my_client_id_secret_from_database', // Laravel Password Grant Client
   email: 'abc@def.com', //or any other field to identificate user
   password: 'pass',
   scope: '*',
};
axios.post('/oauth/token', data).then(...).catch(...)
```

But what about securing the `client_id` and `client_secret`? How can I access only my own apps to use my API? Or access will be granted to anyone who has my client_id and client_secret and I cant hide it from client-side applications like Vue, Angular etc?

Comment: You can't. Period. If this oAuth2, google "implicit grant". That's designed to work with untrusted clients.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the answer :)